# How to change value of JSON property in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have array of items. inside that i have objects 
Please find the structure of one JSON object.

```
[{ApprovedBy: ""
ApprovedDate: "10/12/2019 7:27:24 AM"
AssignedTo: null
ChildClashes: [{_ClashPoint: {X: "0", Y: "0", Z: "0"},…}, {_ClashPoint: {X: "0", Y: "0", Z: "0"},…},…]
ClashFoundDate: "9/12/2019 7:27:24 AM"
ClashID: "109d3ee3-d470-4534-ac72-0b4f2c3c90eb"
ClashImage: null
ClashName: "New Group"
ClashPublishedBy: "Srini"
ClashStatus: "Reviewed"
Comments: null
Description: "Hard"
Distance: "-2.5"
GroupID: null
ID: 456
ImagePath: null
IsGroup: true
Item1: null
Item2: null
RevisionID: "1"
Viewpoint: ""},
 ........]
```

so i want to change the format of approveddate and clashfounddate to dates with MM/dd/YYYY format.
Please let me know how to do it.
please reduce the for loops as much as possible.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). It's a nice library very useful to work with date

Comment: or [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs). dayjs is similar to moment.js. the advantage is that the core bundle is much smaller than moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject date pipe in construtor like

```
 constructor(
    private datePipe:DatePipe
  )
```

and then

```
yourdata.forEach(d=>{
d.ClashFoundDate=this.datePipe.transform(d.ClashFoundDate,'MM/dd/yyyy')
d.ApprovedDate=this.datePipe.transform(d.ApprovedDate,'MM/dd/yyyy')
})
```

[date pipe demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepipe-in-component-anfxgk)